# K8S - Docker - ARM unbutu 64bits - qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped

Tags: docker, kubernetes, raspberry-pi, arm

I installed a K8S cluster on my 4 raspberry pi 4 with 2gb of RAM and 32gb SD cards.

On my master and slave nodes I installed *qemu binfmt-support qemu-user-static* in order to enable the support of ARM CPU for the docker images.

I tried to install Grafana and Prometheus in order to monitor the cluster by doing:

```sh
kubectl apply --filename https://raw.githubusercontent.com/giantswarm/prometheus/master/manifests-all.yaml
```

But the pods `prometheus-node-exporter` failed with the status `CrashLoopBackOff`

When I check the logs `kubectl logs prometheus-node-exporter-dn8t9 -n monitoring` I got the error `qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped`

And I do not know how to solve this issue or where to start looking.

Is there anyone that could help with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at this  and see  since you are running on a raspberry pi 4, your architecture is probably `aarch64` (arm64). So, it seems like the node-exporter DaemonSet K8s manifest is pulling the following image: `prom/node-exporter:v0.14.0` and I looked at [dockerhub and that image tag doesn't have the `aarch64` architecture tag](https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/node-exporter/tags), so it's most likely pulling the `amd64` version causing `qemu` on the node to crash in your case.

You can also see that there's an [`arm64` image starting with `prom/node-exporter:v0.18.0`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/prom/node-exporter/v0.18.0/images/sha256-503d64cf65ad001e4b1946d2d53140d7accbb7c2fa79307c4a90b73b644eb332?context=explore). So, you can try downloading the file editing the node-exporter container to use `v0.18.0` and that should fix the issue with that container. You may also need to update other containers that have matching `arm64` architecture.

‍♀️‍♂️

```sh
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/giantswarm/prometheus/master/manifests-all.yaml
```

Then change:

```yaml
...
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: prometheus-node-exporter
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: prometheus
    component: node-exporter
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus
  template:
    metadata:
      name: prometheus-node-exporter
      labels:
        app: prometheus
        component: node-exporter
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: prom/node-exporter:v0.18.0  Change here
        name: prometheus-node-exporter
        ports:
        - name: prom-node-exp
          #^ must be an IANA_SVC_NAME (at most 15 characters, ..)
          containerPort: 9100
          hostPort: 9100
      hostNetwork: true
      hostPID: true
...
```

✌️

Comment: Thank you, that was it, I had the same error with grafana-core because of the outdated version that was not cross-compiled :) Thank you very much